# Reduzir tamanho do arquivo de Log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Estou em uma saga com meu banco de dados, hoje tenho um arquivo mdf de 11GB e um log de 77GB.
Já pesquisei em diversos forum, apliquei alguns procedimentos de redução via Management(shrink) e via comando como o SHRINKFILE, o banco de dados já se encontra como simple. mas nada o faz reduzir, preciso de ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer backup do seu log de transação (arquivo ldf) e depois executar um shrink. O backup dos logs de transação precisa ser feito da mesma maneira que você faz o backup do banco (arquivo mdf). Caso você não faça, então acontecerá esse comportamento que você está observando.

Exemplo de um comando para fazer backup dos logs de transação:

```
BACKUP LOG [Mobius] TO  DISK = N'G:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\log.trn' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Mobius-Log de Transações  Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

O mesmo pode ser feito pela interface:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um detalhe: o backup dos logs de transação pode ser feito com o banco online e sendo acessado.

Caso você não precise de log de transações, altere o Recovery Mode (ou modo de recuperação) para Simple (simples). Neste cenário, os logs não serão gerados e, assim, você não precisa fazer backup.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note, entretanto, que tudo depende do tipo de banco que você está lidando. Exemplo: é recomendável que um banco de um software ERP tenha log de transações ativos. Um possível cenário seria um backup completo todos os dias e backup das transações de hora em hora.

Já um banco de uma aplicação mais simples, pode ter apenas o backup completo sem a necessidade dos logs de transação.

A vantagem dos logs feitos de hora em hora (por exemplo), é a possibilidade de restaurar um backup até uma determinada hora. Neste caso, basta restaurar o backup completo e, em cima dele, restaurar os backups de hora em hora dos logs de transação até a hora desejada.

Answer (score 1):

Já faz um tempo que desenvolvi esse script para diminuir o log de dados das bases.

Denrto o cursor tem uma linha pra cada versão. A versão 2008 também funciona para 2012

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
declare @bd varchar(100)
declare @file nvarchar(100)
declare @size nvarchar(100)
declare pap_log cursor read_only forward_only for 

SELECT 
    db_name(sf.dbid) as [Database_Name],
    sf.name as [File_Name],
    (sf.size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(file_name(fileid), 'SpaceUsed') AS int)/128.0) AS 'Available_Space_MB'

FROM    master..sysaltfiles sf
WHERE   groupid = 0
and db_name(sf.dbid) not in('model')
ORDER BY    Available_Space_MB  DESC



open pap_log
fetch next from pap_log into @bd,@file,@size
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 
/*2005*/
--set @cmd='backup log '+@bd+' with no_log ;use '+@bd+';dbcc shrinkfile(['+@file+'],0);'
/*2000*/
--set @cmd='backup log '+@bd+' with no_log ;use '+@bd+';dbcc shrinkfile('+@file+',0);'
/*2008*/
set @cmd='use '+@bd+';dbcc shrinkfile('+@file+',0);'
exec sp_executeSQL @cmd
declare @filepath varchar(100)
print ''
print @bd
print rtrim(ltrim(@file+' '+@size))
select @filepath=filename from master..sysaltfiles where name=@file
print @filepath
print ''
fetch next from pap_log into @bd,@file,@size
end
close pap_log
deallocate pap_log
```

Answer (score 0):

Teste o seguinte:

- Faça uma cópia do seu banco;
- Execute `dump tran SEUBANCO with no_log dbcc shrinkdatabase (SEUBANCO,0)`

Outra opção seria desatachar o banco e tentar atachar somente com o arquivo `MDF` na pasta.

Comment: ele não deixa atachar sem o arquivo de log,

sobre a linha de comando, apresenta o seguinte erro
Sintaxe incorreta próxima à palavra-chave 'tran'.

Comment: apenas complementando, eu alterei para simple para efetuar os testes, até então estava full e com backup também full diário, não tenho backup separado de logs, e a base começou a crescer dessa maneira de uns dias para cá

Comment: Acredito que no próximo backup o `log` vai diminuir.

Answer (score 0):

Peguei o mesmo problema recentemente e resolvi desta forma:

> Óbvio: Fazer enquanto ninguém estiver usando a base de dados

1. Backup Full.
2. Botão direito na base e depois detach.
3. Acessar o
   diretório que fica o arquivo do banco de dados, geralmente é:
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA pode mudar dependendo da
   versão;
4. Renomear o arquivo de log que tem a extensão .ldf;
5. No Management Studio, clicar com o botão direito em database, Attach,
   seleciona o arquivo do banco de dados, remove a linha do log que
   aparece em baixo e clica  OK.

Answer (score 0):

Se você tiver certeza de que não precisará do log, ou seja, quer somente reduzir o tamanho do arquivo de log, pode fazer o procedimento abaixo:

1 - Verifique o nome do seu arquivo de log executando o código abaixo:

```
-- Mostra as informações de seus arquivos
USE [NomeDoBanco]-- Alterar nome do banco
GO
EXECUTE sp_helpfile
GO
```

2 - Execute o comando abaixo, colocando o nome do seu arquivo de log:

```
USE [NomeDoBanco];

-- Obs.: Só é possível truncar o log se o banco estiver no modo Simple
ALTER DATABASE [NomeDoBanco] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT;

-- Limpa o arquivo de log.  
DBCC SHRINKFILE (NomeDoArquivo_log, 1); -- Atenção: Colocar o nome do arquivo de log e tamanho que se quer reduzir 

-- Volta o Banco para o modo FULL se for o caso
ALTER DATABASE [NomeDoBanco] SET RECOVERY FULL WITH NO_WAIT;
```