# RDS SQL SERVER Log de Banco de dados Excessivo

Tags: sql-server, amazon-aws

[DB Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHBwc.png)

Na coluna size_on_disk_mb, sua última célula informa que o arquivo de log tem 44GB. Como posso limpá-lo?

Comment: já tentou truncate?

Comment: Aqui tem uma pergunta parecida https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113705/reduzir-tamanho-do-arquivo-de-log

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Reduzir tamanho do arquivo de Log](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113705/reduzir-tamanho-do-arquivo-de-log)